# Docker CP ommitting certain files

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, dockerfile

Docker cp is behaving bizzarely for a certain folder in my container. It's only copying certain files and folders, and ommitting the rest.

I have a container called "script-server" running an nginx reverse proxy. The relative configuration files are stored in /etc/nginx, which I want to pull out and mount them so I can reconfigure easily from the host and restart the container.

Here's the container's folder: [image: container folder]

I then issued the docker cp command from the host to try to pull these files out:

```
docker cp script-server:/etc/nginx ./etc
```

This is what I got out onto the host system:
[image: host folder]
I've read the "docker cp" docs and found nothing useful. I tried the -L option to follow the symlink but still the same result. I'm assuming what's happening is docker is starting to copy everything, then runs into the symlink (that doesnt transfer properly on the host obviously), and then it exits. I removed the symlink and it worked and copied all files.

The underlying problem however is I don't always want to manually bash in, delete or temporarily move symlinks, then copy then restore all symlinks. The other issue is that I can't trust the docker cp command to properly transfer all files. What if I need to install a symlink (I will later).

The weird part is that I've copied from folders before in which the symlinks didnt translate 1:1, and everything transferred to the host, just with broken symlinks which was fine.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar? Is this desired behaviour, and I'm missing something? Any ways to fix it?

Incase it matters, host is ubuntu:19.10 and the docker container is running off of nginx:alpine

Thanks